# How to create a robots.txt file to hide a view page from search engines in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, robots.txt

How to create a robots.txt file in a codeigniter project to hide a view page . where should i place this robots.txt file
currently i have created file like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /application/views/myviewpage.php
```

in side 
`/public_html/folder/robots.txt` (Where i place my `.htaccess` file). Is there any way to test this?

Comment: You don't block the view file as that isn't directly accessible to the crawlers. You need to block the URL that is used to access your view.

Comment: @Jeemusu  should i give the complete url inside robots.txt file like this `http://www.server.com/folder/index.php/mycontroller/my_function`

Comment: You don't need to specify the full url. Just `/index.php/mycontroller/my_function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robots.txt file MUST be placed in the document root of the host. It won’t work in other locations.

If your host is `example.com`, it needs to be accessible at `http://example.com/robots.txt`.

If your host is `www.example.com`, it needs to be accessible at `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`.