# Exclude one of subdomains from being crawled using Robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, umbraco, robots.txt

We have an Umbraco website which has several sub-domains and we want to exclude one of them from being crawled in search engines for now.
I tried to change my Robots.txt file but seems I am not doing it right.

Url: http://mywebsite.co.dl/

subdomain: http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/

My Robots.txt content is as follow:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: sub1.*
```

What I have missed?

Comment: What is document root of sub domain? Is it same as the main domain?

Comment: @anubhava, not necessarily

Comment: If it is not then `Disallow: /` in sub domain's doc root should work. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will block http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl. from being indexed:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /sub1/
```

You can also add another robots.txt file in the sub1 folder with the following code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and that should help as well.

Comment: n Umbraco subdomains do not have separate folders. You can define as many as HostNames you want in Umbraco backend and you would have several subdomains for your website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block anything on `http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/`, your robots.txt [MUST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789713/1591669) be accessible on `http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/robots.txt`.

This robots.txt will block all URLs for all supporting bots:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: In Umbraco subdomains do not have separate folders. You can define as many as HostNames you want in Umbraco backend and you would have several subdomains for your website.

Comment: @amirmoradifard: It doesn’t matter how it’s implemented on the backend. The only thing that matters is the URL that gets used by visitors. So if someone visits a page accessible on `sub.example.com`, the robots.txt **must** be accessible from `sub.example.com/robots.txt`. No other place will work (but you may redirect, I guess).

Comment: It does matter. As far as whole website contains one main root and one robots.txt.
Howlin's answer worked for me.

Comment: @amirmoradifard: Howlin’s first code will not work. Disallowing `/sub1/` does *not* block `http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/` (it would block `http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/sub1/` and anything after that).

Comment: I used his suggestion and manipulated it to : <code>Disallow: sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/* </code> and yes its working.

Comment: @amirmoradifard: It’s working where? This is not valid according to the robots.txt specification. `Disallow` can not contain domains, it contains (beginnings of) URL paths. Your code would block `http://sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/`.

Comment: Yes you are right IF you use Disallow: /sub1.mywebsite.co.dl/* but by getting rid of first slash, it works. At least on my case its working!

Comment: @amirmoradifard: May I ask how you know that it’s working? Even without the beginning slash, it would still be the URL **path**, not the host. So this should not work with any conforming bot/parser.