# robots.txt allow all except few sub-directories

Tags: seo, search-engine, cpanel, robots.txt, shared-hosting

I want my site to be indexed in search engines except few sub-directories. Following are my `robots.txt` settings:

`robots.txt` in the root directory

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Separate `robots.txt` in the sub-directory (to be excluded)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is it the correct way or the root directory rule will override the sub-directory rule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is wrong.

You can’t have a robots.txt in a sub-directory. Your robots.txt [must be placed in the document root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789713/1591669) of your host.

If you want to disallow crawling of URLs whose paths begin with `/foo`, use this record in your robots.txt (`http://example.com/robots.txt`):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /foo
```

This allows crawling everything (so there is no need for `Allow`) except URLs like

- `http://example.com/foo`
- `http://example.com/foo/`
- `http://example.com/foo.html`
- `http://example.com/foobar`
- `http://example.com/foo/bar`
- …

Comment: Can I have a separate robots.txt for sub-domain directory?

Comment: Each subdomain is a new *host*, so for `foo.example.com`, the robots.txt needs to be available at `foo.example.com/robots.txt`. How you achieve this on the server-side doesn’t matter as long as bots see the robots.txt when they visit this reserved URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The above directive is useful if you are developing a new website and do not want search engines to index your incomplete website.
also,you can get advanced infos right [here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-and-configure-your-robots-txt-file)

Comment: This would block everything which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Also note that not all crawlers honor robots.txt, so it's not a replacement for real access control mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage them with robots.txt which sits in the root directory. Make sure to have **allow** patterns before your **disallow** patterns.