# Where to put robots.txt to prevent crawling

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

I'm using `robots.txt` files to prevent crawlers crawling specific pages. When I want to prevent crawling everything in `myfolder` in `/folder/myfolder/` can I put `robots.txt` in `/folder/myfolder/robots.txt` and write:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

or will I have to put `robots.txt` in `/robots.txt` and set:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/myfolder/
```

Who knows that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [robots.txt allow all except few sub-directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495972/robots-txt-allow-all-except-few-sub-directories)

Answer (score 0):

The way `robots.txt` works is off of URL strings, so if you had a project that was 3 directories deep, like this:

```
Home/
  /directory/
    - file 1
    - file 2
    /directory2/
       - file 3
```

---

Putting in this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Will prevent crawling on any url that is `www.yoursite.com`/ (aka your whole site)

---

Putting in something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory1/
```

Will prevent crawling any of the sites/directories that exist in your `directory1` folder. So in our example, `file 1`,`file 2`, and `directory 2` will not get crawled.

---

As far as where you can place it, I always placed it in my home directory, the same place you put your `index.html` file.

Comment: Shouldn’t contain `www.yoursite.com` unless it’s actually part of the URL path (e.g., in a URL like `http://example.com/www.yoursite.com/directory1/`).

Comment: @unor fixed, we use a software that must remove that if it's placed in the field. Thanks for the notice!